# participal Eigenvalues Java (JAMA)

Tags: java, matlab, linear-algebra, jama

I just ported my code from MATLAB to Java, and I need the eigen decomposition of a matrix, specifically I only need the first `k` values not the full decomposition.

However in [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/), the eigen-decomposition class computes the full eigen decomposition. I tried to modify it, but it throws some errors. Is there another similar library?

In MATLAB, the function in question is `eigs(k,A)`

Comment: I've found this one, but never used it! http://code.google.com/p/matrix-toolkits-java/

Comment: You need an iterative method with shifts.

Answer (score 0):

So it's just returning the array of all the eigenvalues. You want to return an array with just the first k values of the array. There are many ways to do this in Java. One is to convert the array to an ArrayList, get a subList of that list, and convert back to an array.

```
double[] mySubArray = new double[k];
for (int i=0; i < k; i++) {
        subArray[i] = myFullArray[i];
    }
```

By the way, this is the library he is referring to: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/

Comment: ok, but here si problem of computing time,...so thios is why, I want to use only first k values  tom compute.no all

Comment: The library is returning a full array of all the eigenvalues. There is nothing you can do about that. You're going to have to iterate through the array somehow to get your smaller array, and then you can perform your calculations on the subarray. You only have to pass through the full array once to get the subarray, which is going to be fast. And please clean up your typos.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you cannot find any existing codes, I guess you should refer to this [thesis](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~rjradke/papers/radkemathesis.pdf) or maybe this [paper](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/sorensen.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try another package named EigenDecomposition in http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/EigenDecomposition.html, there are some methods like `getImagEigenvalue(int i)`, you can get the `i`-th eigenvalue by this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.